# enabling one textbox when content of another textbox changes

Tags: javascript

**I have three text boxes on a form, the default behavior is that the first textbox is enabled but the other two are not. I would like to enable the second text boxes as soon as I start typing in the first textbox or once some text is copied into the first text box.
I have the code below on my form, but it only help with enabling the next text box once I start typing into the textbox before. It does not help/respond when i copy and past the content. Kindly help...**

```
function EnableCopyUsageField(currentField)
{   
   var txtOldItem2 = $get('<%=txtOldItem2.ClientID%>');
   var txtOldItem3 = $get('<%=txtOldItem3.ClientID%>');

   if(currentField == "txtOldItem1")
   {
    txtOldItem2.disabled = false;
    txtOldItem2.style.backgroundColor ='White';
   }

    if(currentField == "txtOldItem2")
    {
    txtOldItem3.disabled = false;
    txtOldItem3.style.backgroundColor ='White';   
    }
}
```

enabling one textbox when content of another textbox changes

Answer (score 0):

U can call your function on both onkeydown and onchange event of textbox. Basically it should change only onkeydown/onkeyup ven if you copy.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="EnableCopyUsageField()" onchange="EnableCopyUsageField()" />
```

Comment: Thanks Shafeeq, I am actually using the onkeypress event, but I want to be able to copy and paste to the textbox. When I copy text from elsewhere and paste, this next textbox does not become enabled.

Answer (score 0):

for copying and pasting, this code solved my problem

```
function EnableFieldOnPaste()
 function EnableFieldOnPaste()
  {
       var txtOldItem1 = $get('<%=txtOldItem1.ClientID%>');
       var txtOldItem2 = $get('<%=txtOldItem2.ClientID%>');

        txtOldItem1.onpaste = function() 
       {
            EnableCopyUsageField("txtOldItem1");
       };

       txtOldItem2.onpaste = function() 
       {
          EnableCopyUsageField("txtOldItem2");
        };
```

}